# Jumping back into XNA T

Tags: dictionary, xna, editor, physics, creation

I just got back into XNA and i started creating a map editor. The game will be a 2D editor that will contain both a Animation, Map, Level, entity, and crafting editor. So far it's going pretty swell right now; but, I think i am missing some key things within the editor

Here let me explain the game I'm trying to make:

- I really want to figure out how to craft a particle editor
- I also want to know how to use farseer phsyics engine (tried getting started on XNATutorial.com, but it's not working correctly).

Thank you in advance for any help you can give me, I'm just trying to see what would be the best things to enter into the game for a 2D action platformer.

Comment: This is too many questions in a single post. You need to be more specific and separate each question into separate posts. You may also want to check out http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ sister site.

Answer (score 0):

To craft a particle editor decide on what you want to be able to do first, then come back with more specific problems, or questions.

Maybe you want to be able to design a particle template. This could define a particle's appearence and behavour.

Then you'd edit a particle emitter template. This would define what particle template to spawn, and what initial properties a particle instance would have.

Then you'd create a particle emitter object in your editor. You could maybe override specific properties in the particle emitter templates.

You could event have a particle emitter template that was a list of particle emitters to spawn, so you could emit different particles from a single editor object.

This would allow you to create lets say a `fire-outside` particle template, which was a yellow circle, a `fire-inside` particle template which was a red partcile, with a shorter life than for former. You'd then define 2 particle emitters, one for each one. Giving spawned particles upwards, but slightly random directions. Then create a multi-emitter called `Fire` or something. Then in the level editor you'd just have to place your `Fire` emitter and in-game you'd get a nice fire effect.

---

Posting a specific problem you have with setting up the physics engine would help.

The overall idea is that you have your game object representation, and you need to create and link them to the physics objects so you can simulate those objects and then update your game objects (for rendering and game logic).

So, when you load your level you'd loop through every physical object and create an equivalent in your physics engine, being sure you can link your game object to the physical one later. Obviously you'd need to keep both systems in sync by adding/removing physical objects as the game progressed and game objects where created/destroyed.

Then in your game loop you'd run your game logic, which might update their positions directly. Then update the physics objects so their position was the equivalent to the game object's. Then run a physics update. Then update your game object's positions according to the physical object's positions.

Comment: Thank you for you help George Duckett, I am not having a problem with creating a physics engine; but, more on the lines of trying to figure out how to use an already crafted physics engine, Farseer physics.                          http://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/

Comment: My post doesn't describe a physics engine, it describes how to generate (editor) and generating those physical objects in-game. You'd have to figure out what objects/classes to create in your physics engine and create them with the proper parameters to start with, then leave it to the physics engine, updating what you render based on the physical objects' properties. I've not used Farseer so can't really say much more.